# how to solve incopmatabllity in php project

Tags: php

I'm trying to use 'yield' in my algorithm and my PHP version is 5.4.

I'm looking for any guidance on using 'yield'.

> this an FP-algorithim it works fine with php 5.5 but the rest of the project use php 5.4

```
    public function find_frequent_itemsets($transactions, $minimum_support){
    $processedTransactions = array();
    $items = array();
    //var_dump($transactions);
    foreach($transactions as $transaction){
      // if(!is_array($transaction)) 
      //continue;
        $processed = array();

        foreach($transaction as $item){

            // check if this item exists ?
            if(array_key_exists($item, $items)){
                $items[$item] += 1;
            }else{
                // not found
                $items[$item] = 1;
            }
            array_push($processed, $item);

        }// every transaction.

        array_push($processedTransactions, $processed);
    }// end first for each (transaction).


    // Remove infrequent items from the item support dictionary.
    foreach(array_keys($items) as $index){
        if($items[$index] < $minimum_support){
            unset($items[$index]);
        }
    }// end loop

    //var_dump($items);
    // sort Transaction in $processedTransactions.
    $sortedTransactions = array();
    //var_dump($processedTransactions);
    foreach($processedTransactions as $currentTransactions){
        $tmp = array();

        foreach($currentTransactions as $item){
            if(array_key_exists($item, $items)){
                // key exits = frequent item.
                //array_push($tmp, array($item, $items[$item]));
                $tmp[$item] = $items[$item];
            }
        }

        // sort based on most frequent item.
        arsort($tmp);
        //var_dump($tmp);
        array_push($sortedTransactions, array_keys($tmp));
    }


    $tree = new FPTree();

    // Add all Transactions.
    foreach($sortedTransactions as $currentTransactions){
        $tree->add($currentTransactions);
    }foreach(find_with_suffix($tree, array(), $minimum_support) as $itemset){
        yield $itemset;
    }

}}
   function find_with_suffix($tree, $suffix, $minimum_support){
    foreach($tree->getItems() as $element){
    $item = $element[0];
    $nodes = $element[1];
    $support = 0;
    foreach($nodes as $n){
        $support += $n->getCount();
    }
      if($support >= $minimum_support && !array_key_exists($item, $suffix)){
        $found_set = array_merge(array($item), $suffix);
        $wanted=array();
        $foo= implode(", ", $found_set) ;
        $wanted[$foo]=$support;
        yield $wanted;                          $condTree=conditional_tree_from_paths($tree->prefixPaths($item),$minimum_support);
      foreach(find_with_suffix($condTree, $found_set, $minimum_support) as s){
            yield $s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove typos from your post and show an example and describe in what makes you believe there is an incompatibility

Comment: pleace read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @Marged most likely OP's running on a server with a lower php version?

Comment: that i use algorithm with version 5.5 and the project is version 5.4 so it sees the yeild function which is only in5.5 as an error

Comment: the project runs on visual studio 2013 with debbug with only 5.4 to be correct

Comment: You develop with php 5.4 and want it to run later on with php 5.5 ? Then update your develop environment.

Comment: no i developed the algorithm on php 5.5 and used yeild and the project uses older version i want something equivalent to yeild in php5.4

Answer (score 0):

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332167/weird-php-yield-error) on stackoverflow tells us, it is rather "costly" to change your algorithm not to use yield and thus make it compatible with a version of php <= 5.4.

On the other side an upgrade to php 5.5 or even better 5.6 is relatively easy. Unfortunately you didn't provide details why you are still with 5.4 and if there are reasons beyond your control that keep you from updating.

I recommend you update your php version because being up to date with software is a matter of security too. Unless you are limited to Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 (which themselves are out of support) you should go for the update.

Comment: I only do this task i can't change the version now the whole project runs on it please any help i don't know what to do  and the deed line is Monday

Comment: @MaiadaWagdy then you have to rewrite your code to not use yield

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work when i tried and i don't know what to do

Comment: @MaiadaWagdy  perhaps it is best if you create a new question or change this one. The focus of what you need is "how to remove yield-function from php algorithm to make it compatible with php < 5.5". Then either show your code with yield or (if it only has small problems) the code where you already tried to remove the yield. And removing the typos will help to attract people because it shows your diligence